# Borrar JTexfield e insertar otro dato

Tags: java, jtextfield

Buenas quiero borrar un JTexfield guardar ese dato en mi variable num1
e insertar otro para llenar la variable num2. 
Estas dos se iran a un metodo en la clase operaciones que recibe esos 2 parametos
aqui parte del codigo

```
JButton btnmulti = new JButton("*");
    btnmulti.setBounds(10, 132, 49, 46);
    contentPane.add(btnmulti);
    btnmulti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(num1==null){

                datos = textField.getText();
                num1= Integer.parseInt(datos);
                textField.setText(null);

            }
            if(num2==null){
                datos = textField.getText();
                num2= Integer.parseInt(datos);
            }

            Operaciones.multiplicacion(num1, num2);
            String res =  Integer.toString(Operaciones.multiplicacion(num1, num2));

            textField.setText(res);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Y que es la pregunta? Que haces con la `NullPointerException`?

Comment: ¿Y cual es tu problema? ¿Que te da una excepción por `null` en `num2` cuando lee el primero e intenta hacer la multiplicación? ¿Qué hace tu método `multiplicacion`?

Comment: aparece eso Exception in thread `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at calculadora.Ventana$2.actionPerformed(Ventana.java:121)`  de hecho no se que hacer pues no me permite hacer eso, el metodo recibe 2  numeros que multiplica y retorna el resultado

Comment: No sé si tendrá que ver pero estás comparando los tipos de datos int num1 y num2 con null, eso no va a funcionar porque el valor por defecto de un integer es 0

Comment: @leobonillab No se sabe qué tipo de dato es `num1` ni `num2`. Pueden ser `Integer` que sí puede ser `null`

Comment: Seria mejor crear dos jTextfield uno para cada variable y mostrar el resultado en otro componente como un jLabel, te recomiendo no hacer textField.setText(null); para limpiar el campo de texto es mejor textField.setText(""); asignarle un texto vació y después verificas que el texto no este vació en vez de verificar por nulos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es añadir una condición antes de hacer la multiplicación para asegurarte que ninguno de los dos operandos es `null`. Modifica esa parte del código añadiendo la condición, con lo que te quedará:

```
if(num1 != null && num2 != null){
    Operaciones.multiplicacion(num1, num2);
    String res =  Integer.toString(Operaciones.multiplicacion(num1, num2));

    textField.setText(res);
}
```